# GTK subclass component

Tags: winapi, gtk, subclassing

What is the GTK equivalent of

```
SetWindowLongPtr((HWND)handle,GWLP_WNDPROC,(LONG_PTR)eventCallback);
```

I want to draw custom stuff in a slider/trackbar/fader control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the "draw" signal, RTM `g_signal_connect (widget, "draw", G_CALLBACK (your_callback), fancy_extra_state_data_you_may_need_or_not);`

Comment: How do I retrieve the old callback?

Comment: It does not get replaced, you can connect multiple callbacks to a signal _unless_ you overwrite the default handler (in this case, for "draw")

Comment: What is their call order then?

Comment: Or if you meant to disconnect, RTM `g_signal_remove_handler`.

Comment: First result on google https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html `in the order they were connected`. Seriously RTM, it is all well documented.